# Html Body Background Image

Tags: html, css

In `body` tag, I added a `background-image`. But the image is repeated 4 times. How to fix that to display it only single time?

HTML code:

```
<body background="image.png"></body>
```

CSS code:

```
body{
    background-image : no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: please try to find the solution yourself before posting your issues here, if you did I guess it would take a couple of  seconds to find the answer for this question!

Answer (score 3):

It's `background-repeat`
body

```
body{
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add style to the body tag using the style attribute:

```
<body style="background-image:url('image.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

Answer (score 1):

**hi now used to this**

```
body{background:url('image.png') no-repeat};
```

**or this**

```
body{
   background-image:url('image.png'); // for your body background
   background-repeat: no-repeat;      // for your body  background repeat 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove background from body and apply your CSS like below.

```
body
{
  background-image:url('image.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  html { 
      background: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/64/1886374.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
   </body>
</html>
```